# Copying nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, nodes

Something strange, or something that I don't understand, is going on. When I try to copy a very simple graph consisting of two nodes connected with an arrow, the following happens: At the left (Cases 1) the figures are parallel because I used the command `below = 15mm of i-0.mid`, that's good but why doen´t it works with 20mm to get it to coincide with the grid? On the right-hand side (cases 2) I use `below = 15mm of i-3` the result is that the "i" and "j" nodes have different spacing. Why is this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth},center}

       \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',auto,node distance=2cm,
      thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
         
         \node at (2.5, 2)    {Cases 1};

        \node[main node] at (0, 0)   (i-0) {i};
        \node[main node] at (5, 0)  (j-0) {j};
        \draw [->]   (i-0) -- (j-0) node[pos=0.5, above] {$x_{ij}=0$};
        \node [below = 1mm of i-0]  {$\in X$};
        \node [below = 1mm of j-0]  {$\in X$};
        \node [above = 1mm of j-0]  {$(i^+,q_{ij})$};
        

        \node [main node, below = 15mm of i-0.mid] (i-1) {i};
        \node [main node, below = 15mm of j-0.mid] (j-1) {j};
        \draw [->]   (i-1) -- (j-1) node[pos=0.5, above] {$0 < x_{ij} < q_{ij}$};
        \node [below = 1mm of i-1]  {$\in X$};
        \node [below = 1mm of j-1]  {$\in X$};
        \node [above = 1mm of j-1]  {$(i^+,q_{ij}-x_{ij})$};
        
        
        \node [main node, below = 15mm of i-1.mid] (i-2) {i};
        \node [main node, below = 15mm of j-1.mid] (j-2) {j};
        \draw [->]   (i-2) -- (j-2) node[pos=0.5, above] {$x_{ij} = q_{ij}$};
        \node [below = 1mm of i-2]  {$\in X$};
        \node [below = 1mm of j-2]  {$\in \overline{X}$};
        
         \node at (9.5, 2)    {Cases 2};
        
        \node [main node, right = 65mm of i-0] (i-3) {i};
        \node [main node, right = 65mm of j-0] (j-3) {j};
        \draw [->]   (i-3) -- (j-3) node[pos=0.5, above] {$x_{ji}=0$};
        \node [below = 1mm of i-3]  {$\in X$};
        \node [below = 1mm of j-3]  {$\in \overline{X}$};


        \node [main node, below = 15mm of i-3] (i-4) {i};
        \node [main node, below = 15mm of j-3] (j-4) {j};
        \draw [<-]   (i-4) -- (j-4) node[pos=0.5, above] {$0 < x_{ji} < q_{ji}$};
        \node [below = 1mm of i-4]  {$\in X$};
        \node [below = 1mm of j-4]  {$\in X$};
        \node [above = 1mm of j-4]  {$(i^-,x_{ji})$};
         
        \node [main node, below = 15mm of i-4] (i-5) {i};
        \node [main node, below = 15mm of j-4] (j-5) {j};
        \draw [<-]   (i-5) -- (j-5) node[pos=0.5, above] {$x_{ji} = q_{ji}$};
        \node [below = 1mm of i-5]  {$\in X$};
        \node [below = 1mm of j-5]  {$\in X$};
        \node [above = 1mm of j-5]  {$(i^-,x_{ji})$};       
        
        \draw [cyan, densely dotted] (0,-6) grid (12,3); 

    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your copies are not correct since on the side you wrote `below = 15mm of i-0.mid` while on the right side you wrote `below = 15mm of i-3` and not `below = 15mm of i-3.mid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would draw your image on the following way:

- not use `adjustbox`, if image is larger as desired I would rather reduce `node distance` and font size
- define the size of circles by using `text height` and `text depth` so, that all of them will have the same size
- use positions syntax as is defined in the `positioning` library
- for edge labeling use `quotes` library
- for nodes labels use labels (above, below)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, 
                positioning,
                quotes
                }

\begin{document}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth,auto,
node distance = 11mm and 33mm, 
     N/.style = {circle, draw, thick,
                 text height=1em, text depth=0.4ex,
                 font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
every label/.append style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\small},
every edge quotes/.style  = {inner sep=2pt, font=\small}
                        ]
% left column, 0
\node (i-0) [N,
             label=below:$\in X$]                   {i};
\node (j-0) [N, right=of i-0,
             label=below:$\in X$,
             label={$(i^+,q_{ij})$}]                {j};
    \draw [->]   (i-0) to ["{$x_{ij}=0$}"] (j-0);
% 1
\node (i-1) [N, below = of i-0,
             label=below:$\in X$]           {i};
\node (j-1) [N, below = of j-0,
             label=below:$\in X$,
             label={$(i^+,q_{ij}-x_{ij})$}] {j};
    \draw [->]   (i-1) to ["$0 < x_{ij} < q_{ij}$"] (j-1);
% 2
\node (i-2) [N, below = of i-1,
             label=below:$\in X$]           {i};
\node (j-2) [N, below = of j-1,
             label=below:$\in \overline{X}$]     {j};
    \draw [->]   (i-2) to ["{$x_{ij}=q_{ji}$}"] (j-2);

% right column, 3
\node (i-3) [N, right=7mm of j-0,
             label=below:$\in X$]           {i};
\node (j-3) [N, right=of i-3,
             label=below:$\in \overline{X}$,
             label={$(i^+,q_{ij})$}]        {j};
    \draw [->]   (i-3) to ["{$x_{ji}=0$}"] (j-3);
% 4
\node (i-4) [N, below = of i-3,
             label=below:$\in X$]           {i};
\node (j-4) [N, below = of j-3,
             label={$(i^+,x_{ji})$},
             label=below:$\in X$]           {j};
    \draw [->]   (i-4) to ["$0 < x_{ji} < q_{ji}$"] (j-4);
% 5
\node (i-5) [N, below = of i-4,
             label=below:$\in X$]           {i};
\node (j-5) [N, below = of j-4,
             label={$(i^+,x_{ji})$},
             label=below:$\in X$]           {j};
    \draw [->]   (i-5) to ["{$x_{ji}=q_{ji}$}"] (j-5);
%%%%    titles
\node [above=1em] at ($(i-0.north)!0.5!(j-0.north)$)    {Cases 1};
\node [above=1em] at ($(i-3.north)!0.5!(j-3.north)$)    {Cases 2};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for the useful indications and how to improive the code.